# How to Ignore Mouse Input with Unity's New Input System while Clicking on an UI Element?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I receive input from the mouse with the `New Input System`, but I do not want to receive input while the mouse is on any `UI` object, regardless of it being over or under any `non-UI` object. I tried `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`. It seems to work, but it also gives a warning every time input is received.

> Calling IsPointerOverGameObject() from within event processing (such as from InputAction callbacks) will not work as expected; it will query UI state from the last frame UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:IsPointerOverGameObject () ...

Here is my code:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
  mouseClick.Enable();
  mouseClick.performed += MousePressed;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
  mouseClick.performed -= MousePressed;
  mouseClick.Disable();
}

private void MousePressed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
  if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

  Ray ray = _playerCam.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
  RaycastHit hit;
  ...
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you not want to receive any input while on a `UI object`, even if it's under a `non-UI object`?

Comment: Let's clarify, you want to receive mouse events in the "game" (terrain, units, whatever) but to not click or right click or interact in general with GOs that are part of the UI?

Comment: @IDBB I am very sorry for the confusion I created. It is ok if it's under a non-UI object. The UI object I was talking about is a button specifically. I don't want my character to move, if I'm clicking the button.

Comment: @TheNomad I'm sorry for the confusion. I want to interact with GOs that are part of the UI whatever the case, but do not want to  receive mouse events in the "game" (terrain, units, etc.) while I'm interacting with UI (ex. clicking a button). I mean, If I'm clicking a button, I don't want raycast to reach terrain and provide player to move that way. but the button always should work

Comment: Alright, then I'd suggest using `PointerEventData` to check whether you're targeting any `UI`.

Comment: @NewOne Is this something that worries you or did it actually happen? There is no reason to try hacks, the proper way to restrict this is to use layers. UI GOs should **always** be on the UI layer and you can use whatever other layer for the game (units, buildings, terrain, water etc.) and set layer masks when raytracing: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html . Did this approach not work for you or why are you trying such complicated techniques like modifying the UI input event system)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
private void MousePressed(InputAction.CallbackContext _)
{
    PointerEventData eventData = new(EventSystem.current)
    {
        position = Input.mousePosition
    };

    List<RaycastResult> results = new();

    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventData, results);

    if (results.Count > 0)
            return;

    // ...
}
```

If you want to check whether you've clicked on any `UI` object, you can implement it using `EventSystem`.

First we get the `PointerEventData` from the `current` `EventSystem`  and assign its `PointerEventData.position` to `Input.mousePosition`. We don't have to convert it, as the `position` takes coordinates in `screen space`, which is also the space of the returned value. This can be also implemented like this. Whatever feels more readable for you.

```cs
Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

PointerEventData eventData = new(EventSystem.current);

eventData.position = mousePos;
```

Then we call the `EventSystem.current.RaycastAll` method for previously set `PointerEventData` and store the `List<RaycastResult>` in our created `results`. This method gets every `UI Object` which has `Graphic.raycastTarget` set to `true`. Otherwise those objects don't even respond to user's clicks.

If the list isn't empty, we break the method, because there's at least one `UI` found. Now, if you want to check this `UI` being e.g. a `Button`, you've mentioned in comments, you can enumerate through its items and check for it.

```cs
foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
{
    if (result.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>())
        return;
}
```

Additionally, you can find your `UI` by a tag.

```cs
foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
{
    if (result.gameObject.CompareTag("MyButton"))
        return;
}
```

Notice that `CallbackContext`'s name is `_`, as we don't need it. In your case its value is `float`, which returns `1` if pressed and `0` if not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I tried what you said, but I got an error like "InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'Vector2' from control '/Mouse/leftButton' bound to action 'Land/Move[/Mouse/leftButton]' (control is a 'ButtonControl' with value type 'float')...".

Comment: You're right, I am sorry, I made a mistake forgetting that it returns a `float` with `1` if pressed and `0` if not, not a `Vector2` meaning position. I've adjusted my answer to fix this issue in another way without using the `CallbackContext`.